# Tool or eclipse base plugin available for generate test cases for SalesForce platform related Apex classes

Tags: eclipse-plugin, salesforce, apex-code

Can any one please tell me is there any kind of tools or eclipse base plugins available for generate relevant test cases for SalesForce platform related Apex classes. It seems with code coverage they are not expecting out come like we expect with JUnit, they want to cover whether, test cases are going through the flows of the source classes (like code go through). 
Please don't get this post in wrong, I don't want anyone is going to write test cases for my codes :). I have post this question due to nature of SalesForce expecting that code coverage should be. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although Salesforce requires a certain percentage of code coverage for your test cases, you really need to be writing cases that check the results to ensure that the code behaves as designed.

So, even if there was a tool that could generate code to get 100% coverage of your test class, it wouldn't be able to test the results of those method calls, leaving you with a false sense of having "tested code".

I've found that breaking up long methods into separate, sometimes static, methods makes it easier to do unit testing.  You can test each individual method, and not worry so much about tweaking parameters to a single method so that it covers all execution paths.

Comment: Hi Tomlogic! Thanks a lot for your favorable feed back. Have a nice time!

Answer (score 0):

it's now possible to generate test classes automatically for your class/trigger/batch. You can install "Test Class Generator" app from AppExchange and see it working.

This would really help you generating test class and saves lot of your development time.